how to integrate of MS teams with cucumber-testNG-extentsparkreports
I recently tried sending summary reports of testcases everytime i run in my local to ms teams channels but got blockers all my way
can anyone suggest me how to do it if you have experience with it
Thanks in advance
I tried this way but not working
package Runner;
 import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
 import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

 public class TestSuite {

     ExtentReports extent;
 
     @BeforeSuite
     public void setup() {
         ExtentSparkReporter sparkReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter("extent-spark.html");
         extent = new ExtentReports();
         extent.attachReporter(sparkReporter);
     }

     @AfterSuite
     public void tearDown() {
         extent.flush();
         ExtentReportSummary summaryGenerator = new ExtentReportSummary(extent);
         String summary = summaryGenerator.generateSummary();
         TeamsNotifier.sendSummaryToTeams(summary);
     }
 }


